# Create a new ipynb file not found

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use Pycharm to create A Jupyter Notebook using Pycharm. But such option is not found in the list, as I see in many tutorials.
How I can create a ipynb file in PyCharm ?

[image]

Comment: Is it Community Edition? It doesn't support Jupyter notebooks, you need Professional.